# Image of the preimage of a set $A$ is a proper subset of $A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given a function $f: M \to N$ and the set $A \subset N$. Prove that $f(f^{-1}(A))\subset A$.

I have already proved that $f(f^{-1}(A))\subseteq A$ by showing that $ x \in f(f^{-1}(A)) \Rightarrow  x \in A$. How can I show that $f(f^{-1}(A))$ can be at most just a proper subset of $A$?

Comment: You can't. What happens if $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that, for most authors, $\subset$ means $\subseteq$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't know that. So, this is what is happening in this context?

Comment: In this context, it is clear to me that they mean the same thing.

Comment: @joeren1020: $f(f^{-1}(A))\subset A$: If $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$, then we are done. if $f^{-1}(A)\neq\emptyset$ and $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in f^{-1}(A)=\{x'\in M: f(x')\in A\}$, then $y\in A$. If in addition $f$ is surjective then equality holds.